# How can I troubleshoot a U0208 DTC code on a 2009 Land Rover LR2?

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting, obd-ii, land-rover

How can I troubleshoot a code [U0208](http://obdii.pro/en/code/U0208) on a 2009 Land Rover LR2? It has a 3.2L engine. Thanks!

Comment: Your question has come up for deletion because it is very broad and answering it is beyond the scope of what we do here. What you can do, is do a web search for your make and model of car and this DTC and see what you find. When you have specific questions about what you find, then the question would be accepted. And thanks for contributing and we look forward to seeing more information on this so you can get the resolution you need.

Comment: @cdunn I don't think this is really that broad we have a code, engine, make and model. Maybe resolve isn't the correct word for the question, but it's fairly specific.

Comment: So called "Universal" codes usually involve faults with the communication bus,and the OBD system itself - an auxiallary system unrelated to vehicle control, emissions, or fueling.   It's a rare beast.  Verify that you *really do have this code* before you spend too much effort.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this site](http://upkeep.us/OBDII/OBD2/Land-Rover/piart.php?art=2797), this is a "lost connection" issue with "Seat Control Module A." Find the location of the control module, make sure it's plugged in and that there's no corrosion at the connector.

Comment: Seat Control Module A is the Driver Seat Module. You should also verify power, ground and CAN Bus integrity.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this resource](http://repairdata.cnlaunch.com/pdf/2015/01/09/5a29ce1f-6d5c-417e-943c-f9ffbcf46f16.pdf) by searching on the terms "u0208 land rover." The linked document provides a step-by-step troubleshooting procedure. Try working through it and post a more specific question if you get stuck.

Somethings to keep in mind / look for:

- Assume that it is a single problem until you've exhausted that option.
- Check the fuse.
- Look for corroded connections, signs of water/liquid getting near the controller and its connectors.
- Look for physical damage to the wires serving the controller, the seat, and the door (for the mirror).
- See if there are any other codes set (see the procedure notes).